# List only unassigned values for many to many field in Django

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I have two models as follows:

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Season(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    fruits = models.ManyToManyField(Fruit, related_name='seasonal_fruit')
```

I want to add the fruits to the `Season` if only they are not assigned to any other `Season` object.

Also, I want to display the list of these distinct (i.e. not assigned to any other `Season` object) in the `SeasonAdmin`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

- You need to follow this : [Django Many To Many Field Admin Custom](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany)
- Update your Admin.py file like :

```
class SeasonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "fruit":
            f = [x for x in Fruit.objects.all()]
            s = [y for y in Season.objects.all()]
            for a in y:
                for b in y.fruit.all():
                    f.remove(b)
            kwargs["queryset"] = f
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did adjust this code a little to get it working for  admin. :)